# 2016 Hyundai automatic Elantra cranks but won’t start

Tags: electrical, fuel-system, hyundai, elantra

My wife went to leave for work this morning and her car won’t start. I go out and the engine turns over then grinds. Tried to jump it off but same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: please give more information,does the ignition work and does the engine get fuel.

Comment: Yes ignition works and can hear fuel pump kick on when I turn the key

Comment: so you can see the spark when you run the starter,next step is to take a look at the spark plugs are they dry or wet,this will show you if the engine gets fuel.

Comment: @trondhansen I get the feeling that your question about the ignition wasn’t clear enough.  I think that the OP probably wasn’t telling you that they have a spark.  I think that they probably are just saying that the lights on the dash light up as normal, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Hyundai has a long warranty. You may want to check if it is still under warranty before you tamper with it.

Comment: @HandyHowie i am afraid you are right,i make this error sometimes i think people know the same as i do i am sorry.

Comment: So the engine was flooded (don’t know what my wife did) there was no air almost sounded like the choke was stuck like back in the old days. Saw an article on another site and talked about the throttle body being stuck shut. I floored the gas all the way to the floor with my right foot and the left was on the brake and it started right up. Drove it around the block rode like normal.

Comment: Yep just missed out on our warranty my wife has a long commute and are over on the miles

Comment: "engine turns over then grinds" explain grinds please.

Comment: Sounded like the starter was grinding

Comment: @Bjdd322 if flooding was the issue, and holding the pedal resolved the issue in your case, consider adding that as you own answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

My car was having issues starting and would cut
off while stopped.  Did this on and off for about 2 weeks.  Check engine never came on so could not find issue through diagnostic machine.  Finally the check engine light came on and it was the Crank Shaft position sensor.  $70 part, total repair was $125.  2016 Elentra.